# Illustrator: how to extend a point selection to the full stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, stroke, shortcuts, anchor-point

Is there a way to extend a point selection to its stroke ?

I want to:

- select a point
- (magic shortcut ?)
- have the whole stroke selected

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, click the anchor point **once** to select it, then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the same point **again**, to select the entire path.

Answer (score 1):

One **can** merely click the object with the **Selection Tool**  (Black arrow) to select it in its entirety. Or you can <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+click when using the **Direct Selection Tool** (White Arrow) to select entire objects.

If you **must** start with merely a single anchor selected, and **must** use a shortcut without any further clicks...

Lock, then unlock, and the entire object will be selected....

- Select a single anchor
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Object > Lock > Selection)
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> (Object > Unlock All)

This will result in the entire object being selected after it is unlocked.

You can do the same thing with `Object > Hide` rather than locking, if you'd prefer to hide.

- Select a single anchor
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (Object > Hide > Selection)
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (Object > Show All)